# Terminology and being able to firing Javascript in Google Tag Manager -

Tags: javascript, facebook

[image: Google Tag Manager]

I use social media buttons (Facebook, LinkedIn etc) throughout my site.

I do not want the Javascript that enables the showing of social media buttons to be published on certain pages. I've tried to get this to work but it seems that I don't understand the terminology?

What should I be selecting if I do NOT want the Javascript to be present in directories that have this path:

```
mysite.com/subscriber/
```

and

```
mysite.com/organizer/
```

The options in the first dropdown are:

```
Page URL
Page Hostname
Page Referrer
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you add a slash before the values, i.e. `/organizer` and `/subscriber` then your tags will fire properly.

Or you could choose `matches RegEx` instead and use one trigger that fires when page url matches the value `(\/organizer\/|\/subscriber\/)`